Casting from 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'
I encountered an error saying that "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'." Isn't it too unlogical? How come? When I try the following on immediate windows, the output as such that
reader.GetInt16(mycolumn_ordinal_value)
999
reader.GetInt32(mycolumn_ordinal_value)
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll

At DB level (sqlserver), it is defined as mycolumn smallint.
When I ask it to Github Copilot it says literally,

However, when you try to use reader.GetInt32(mycolumn), it throws a
System.InvalidCastException. This is unusual(you can't be serious bruh!!) because GetInt32
should be able to handle any value that GetInt16 can handle, since
the range of a 32-bit integer (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) is
much larger.

I don't understand it. Any idea?

I'm willing to bet it has nothing to do with casting and everything to do with boxing.
While an implicit cast from int16 to int32 is available, you can't unbox an int16 to int32

It's logical if the field has a different type or if you're trying to store the value in a field of the wrong type. We can't guess. Instead of randomly generated answers post your own code, query, table schema and actual full exception text, not just the message.

Assuming this is SqlDataReader, this behaviour is documented in the Remarks section - "No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a 32-bit signed integer."

Random text generators know nothing about ADO.NET or anything else. They only know about the statistics of word combinations. They won't even give a higher weight to the ADO.NET docs or implementation. They'll give the same weight to copy-pasta or other randomly generated bad articles, like those found in ..... certain sites

What's on the left? Are you assigning the result of the call to an int or long or something else?

This happens because when you call SqlDataReader.GetInt32() for a short it ends up internally calling code like return (Int32)this.Value where this.Value is a boxed short - which is where the exception arises.

@MatthewWatson can you please write it an answer, I want to accept it. I tried to simulate it as you say var a = (Int32)(object)(short)5;

@PanagiotisKanavos it has nothing to do with any sort of ORM.

@SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire I didn't say anything about ORMs. ADO.NET is .NET's data access library.  SqlDataReader is part of ADO.NET, in fact, until recently it was packaged in the runtime itself. Only recently was it extracted into the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library

This happens because when you call SqlDataReader.GetInt32() for a short it ends up internally calling code like return (Int32)this.Value where this.Value is a boxed short - which is where the exception arises.
We can look at the source for SqlDataReader.GetInt32():
override public Int32 GetInt32(int i) {
    ReadColumn(i);
    return _data[i].Int32;
}

That _data is an array of type SqlBuffer. The definition of SqlBuffer.Int32 is:
internal Int32 Int32 {
    get {
        ThrowIfNull();

        if (StorageType.Int32 == _type) {
            return _value._int32;
        }
        return (Int32)this.Value; // anything else we haven't thought of goes through boxing.
    }
}

The crucial thing here is that because the storage type doesn't match, it returns (Int32)this.Value. In this case, this.Value is of type object, and is actually a boxed version of that actual underlying type - for your example that's Int16.
Hence it's trying to cast a boxed Int16 to an Int32 and it throws the exception.
